# Change in the jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I wanted to install feature engine so i can use it with ($ pip install -U feature-engine),when i restarded the kernel i started having some errors in kmeans  and the output of many cells changed.
here are the screenshots:[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lapjf.png)  [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldFPe.png) (last checkpoint)
The output of pipeline changed also : [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOSBg.png)   , [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr0UE.png)
Now even when i go back to the last checkpoint or in a new nootebook  and i run all i still have the same problem

How can i go back to what was before installing this module ? and why those this outputs changed
Thanks